# how to compare two excel sheet using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, hashtable

I have last month excel sheet with following
[image]

Current month excel sheet with following
[image]

Now i would like find what is new server Name added in current month then list them out as shown below
[image]

So far i got following code. any idea would be appreciated ? i will be scheduling this with windows scheduler task .This should be powershell since i will be adding more code later how to pick right excel sheet from SMB share.

i am trying this

```
$oldbk = Import-Excel -Path '\\hcohesity05\cohesity_reports\2022\7\07-29\Cohesity_FETB_Report-2022-07-29-14-26-48.xlsx'
$newbk = Import-Excel -Path '\\hcohesity05\cohesity_reports\2022\8\08-26\Cohesity_FETB_Report-2022-08-26-14-26-48.xlsx'

$Compare = Compare-Object $oldbk $newbk -Property "Server Name" -includeDifferent -PassThru 
        $Compare | Export-Excel -Path '.\diff.xlsx'
```

but getting message
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'includeDifferent'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code I'm assuming you're only interested in finding the servers **not present** in the old Excel document, if that's the case you only need [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2) for filtering:

```
$oldbk = Import-Excel -Path 'path\to\oldfile.xlsx'
Import-Excel -Path 'path\to\newfile.xlsx' | Where-Object {
    $_."Server Name" -notin $oldbk."Server Name"
} | Export-Excel -Path 'path\to\diff.xlsx'
```

As for the error message, [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.2) does not have a `-IncludeDifferent` parameter and shows differences between two objects **by default**.

```bash
$Compare = Compare-Object $oldbk $newbk -Property "Server Name" -PassThru
```